# Admob banner overlaps with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

Recently, I have been trying to fix this problem but i was unable to do that. As reviewed by the user, my adbanner overlaps the textview in my scrollview on some devices though it works perfect on my Samsung Galaxy Fit.

here is my full XML :

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >      
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tx1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5px" />        
    <ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50px" >    
        <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">             
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tx2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25dp" 
                android:textColor="#000000" />              
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tx3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="20dp" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="1px" />
                 </LinearLayout>        
    </ScrollView>       
</LinearLayout> 
<com.google.ads.AdView  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="XXX"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />   
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated to solve this. **Samsung apps' certification team sent me [this](http://www.searchplus.tk/temp/1.wmv) video of the defect.**

Comment: have you consider using a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that! : @Dyna

Comment: Your first linearlayout is "fill_parent" in height so normally it SHOULD overlapse the ad.The same for the scrollview, it means it is supposed to take ALL the place of the parent container leaving no space for the other view. And using orientation with relativelayout is useless.

Comment: @Yume : What if I add layout_marginBottom="50px" to my Linear layout which is filling parent height.! and I am still confused that why its still working on some devices?

Comment: I assume those other device have diferent version of Android ? You can try padding maybe. Maybe it works but i advice you to redo this kind of layout.xml bit by bit. This is no clean solution

Comment: Yes! I think you are right. The other devices have different version of android.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your current LinearLayout xml:

```
     android:paddingBottom="50dp"
```

Answer (score -2):

Use dp when referring to pixels, not px. In your scrollView, try both layout_paddingBottom="50dp" and layout_marginBottom="50dp" and see if that is your desired solution

Comment: layout_paddingBottom?